# Cannot Auto Permanent Delete File on Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

i try to use [google script](https://script.google.com) for delete file without going to trash, but have an error on :

```
Drive.Files.remove(File.getId())
```

This the full script :

```
function DeleteOldFiles() { 

var Folders = new Array( 'FOLDER_ID_HERE', 'FOLDER_ID_HERE' ); 
var Files; 
Logger.clear(); 
for each (var FolderID in Folders) { 
Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID);
 Files = Folder.getFiles(); 
while (Files.hasNext()) { 
var File = Files.next(); 
if (new Date() - File.getLastUpdated() > 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) { 


 File.setTrashed(true); // Places the file int the Trash folder 
      //Drive.Files.remove(File.getId()); // Permanently deletes the file 
   Logger.log('File ' + File.getName() + ' was deleted.'); 
    } 
} 
} 
    if(Logger.getLog() != '') 
    MailApp.sendEmail('YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS', 'Backups have been removed from Google Drive', Logger.getLog()); }
```

when it uncomment “//"

how to fix this ?

here the screenshot :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCiSF.png

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*In order to use the `Drive.Files.remove()` method in Apps Script, you need to activate the Advanced Drive service.*

#### Resolution:

From the Apps Script User Interface, click on `Resources > Advanced Google Services` like so:

[image]

In the new window pop-up, scroll down to `Drive API` and while making sure that `v2` is selected in the dropdown, click the slider on the right hand-side so that instead of 'off' it turns green and switches to 'on':

[image]

From here you can use Advanced Google Drive services such as `Drive.Files.remove()`.

Comment: thank you buddy, your tutorial went well, thank you very much